# I'm writing a ScrumDinger application according to the Apple manual. I have a large number of errors, but I want to fix this particular one

Tags: ios

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa4r1.png)[image: 1]

The error "Generic struct 'StateObject' requires that 'ScrumTimer' conform to 'ObservableObject'" occurs in Swift when I use a StateObject with a ScrumTimer type that does not conform to the ObservableObject protocol.

Implemented the ObservableObject protocol. I added the ObservableObject protocol to the ScrumTimer class or struct declaration. But it did not help

[image: 2]

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine


class scrumTimer: ObservableObject {
}
    struct MeetingView: View {
        @Binding var scrum: DailyScrum
        @StateObject var scrumTimer = ScrumTimer()
    
        var body: some View {
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16.0)
                    .fill(scrum.theme.mainColor)
                VStack {
                    MeetingHeaderView(secondElapsed: scrumTimer.secondElapsed, secondRemaining: scrumTimer.secondRemaining, theme: scrum.theme)
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(lineWidth:24, antialiased: true)
                    MeetingFooterView(speakers: scrumTimer.speakers, skipAction: scrumTimer.skipSpeaker)
                }
                
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(scrum.theme.accentColor)
                .onAppear(){
                    scrumTimer.reset(lengthInMinutes:scrum.lengthInMinutes, attendees: scrum.attendees )
                    scrumTimer.startScrum()
                }
                .onDisappear{
                    scrumTimer.stopTimer()
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            }
        }
        
        init(scrum: Binding<DailyScrum>){
            _scrum = scrum
        }
        
        struct MeetingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                MeetingView(scrum:.constant(DailyScrum.sampleData[0]))
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add any relevant information as **text**. Images are a pain to read and difficult to copy and paste from.

Answer (score 0):

In your first screenshot variable is initialized with `ScrumTimer` type. But your type in the top of the screen is started with lowercased letter `scrumTimer`

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question after you told me what to fix. It did not help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75756122/im-writing-a-scrumdinger-application-according-to-the-apple-manual-i-have-a-la#:~:text=enter%20image%20description%20here

Comment: @StateObject var scrumTimer = scrumTimer() // error Circular reference

Comment: classes can not be started with lowercasse symbol... your classname should be ScrumTimer in defiition and in variable initializatio